# How to read large files(with rownames) with scan in this situation in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a text file which is a 1000 Row * 40001 Column table.

The first Column of the file is a string and the other columns are some `float` numbers, such as this:

```
A 2 3 4.54 .... 11.23
B 6 6 7 ....    23.45
```

I want to read this file into a matice but `read.table` seems not very efficient for large files, so I think `scan` may be the right tool for that?

However, `scan` can only accept numbers as input by default. If I want non-number as input, I need to change the `what` parameter. But as there're 40000+ columns, I can't assign the type of input for each input..

Does anyone know how to use it? Thanks!

Comment: you could put the row names in the na.strings arg in scan, then add them afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `what` argument and specify a list of types (like `colClasses`).

```
Lines <-
"A 2 3 4.54 11.23
B 6 6 7 23.45"
Data <- (scan(textConnection(Lines), what=c(list(NULL), rep(0,4))))
(Data <- do.call(cbind, Data))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]
# [1,]    2    3 4.54 11.23
# [2,]    6    6 7.00 23.45
```

Answer (score 2):

The read.table function becomes much more efficient if you use the colClasses parameter:

```
inp <- read.table(filnam, colClasses= c(NULL, rep("numeric", 40000) )
```